# textfield with background image

Tags: html, css, input-field

[image]

It must be a common issue but I really can't find any solutions for it.  There is a textfield (texts will be written from right to left) and it has a curvy-side background image. The problem is the cursor must stay only in the red box area.

The following is the four solutions I've come up with.

1 - **Create a div with the background image and put a textfield in it.**

Unless the textfield is transparent, it will cover the background image. Setting it transparent using CSS?  I'm worried about some browsers not supporting it :(

2 - **Chop the background image into 3 parts(left - mid - right) and connect them all together. The textfield is positioned in the mid div.**

This is okay... but the code will look messy :S  ... :before :after selectors come in handy maybe?

3 - **background image stays the same but the textfield size is decreased and positioned center.**

This will be the best solution for it but clueless how to do.

4 - **Hey, WHY NOT JUST USE CSS3 ??**

The background image has a company logo and this cannot be done with CSS... :(

Would there be a better solution that supports all the browsers?  :(

Code ---

```
<div id="navigation" class="float-right">                   
<ul>
    <li><?php echo anchor('.', 'HOME'); ?></li>
    <li><?php echo anchor('company', 'COMPANY'); ?></li>
    <li><?php echo anchor('#', 'PRODUCTS'); ?></li>
    <li><?php echo anchor('#', 'SUPPORT'); ?></li>
    <li><?php echo anchor('contact', 'CONTACT'); ?></li>
    <li><input type="text"></input></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

CSS ---

```
#navigation ul li{
display: inline;
}
#navigation ul li input
{
background:url(../images/common/search_bar.jpg) no-repeat left top;
width:113px;
height:18px;
border: 0px;
text-align: right;
outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div id="navigation" class="fr">                    
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo anchor('.', 'HOME'); ?></li>
        <li><?php echo anchor('company', 'COMPANY'); ?></li>
        <li><?php echo anchor('#', 'PRODUCTS'); ?></li>
        <li><?php echo anchor('#', 'SUPPORT'); ?></li>
        <li><?php echo anchor('contact', 'CONTACT'); ?></li>
        <li><div id="search-bar"><input type="text"></input></div></li>
    </ul>
</div>

#search-bar
{
    background:url(../images/common/search_bar.jpg) no-repeat top left;
    width:115px;
    height:18px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#search-bar input
{
    width:80px;
    height:18px;
    text-align: right;
    border: 0px;
    outline: none;
    background:url(../images/common/transparent.png) repeat-x;
}
```

I succeeded it in this way. Instead of using CSS3 transparent, i just created 1px width transparent png image file and used it as the input field background. I'm not sure if it's the best way... but it seems working.

Answer (score 1):

Add some padding right and left so the background image will still appear but the text will never go on the side.

Comment: I've tried but it didn't go quite well... :(  I've posted some of my codes.